# Python - how to use a[::] in a loop?

Tags: python

So I am currently a student at a school studying python, I cant seem to solve a problem in my small project.

```
a=input('Line: ').upper()
ab=[]
ac=[]
while a:
 ab.append(a)
 a=input('Line: ').upper()
 ac=a[0:1]

ba=ab[0]
ba=ba[0]
bb=ab[1]
bb=bb[1]
bc=ab[2]
bc=bc[2]
bd=ab[3]
bd=bd[3]


print(ba + bb + bc + bd)
```

I am trying to make the program pick a certain character from each column.
My current code works but it wont work with more than 4 columns of inputs.
I took away the ba,bb,bc,bd function and replaced it with:

```
a=input('Line: ').upper()
ab=[]
ac=[]
ad=[]
ae=[]
while a:
 ab.append(a)
 a=input('Line: ').upper()
 ac=a[0:1]
 ad=ac[0:]
 ae.append(ad)


 print(ae)
```

But I don't know how to make the a[::] switch from grabbing the first character from the list to grabbing the second character from the next column.
The output I want is:

The output I am looking for is:

```
Line: (W)ow!
Line: W(h)o would've thought?
Line: Th(e) answer
Line: Tre(n)dily
Line: Wand(e)rs
Line: The e(v)ening
Line: Past e(e)rie
Line: Road co(r)ners
Line: 
WHENEVER
```

And then the first 2 codes were my attempts. I dont know how to use the slice function to grab the letters from the input. the () are the string output I want

Comment: Show the desired input and output example.

Comment: Second ^. If I follow though. Could you have a counter outside the `while` keep track of the position? `count = 0` and each time in the loop it says `result.append(a[count])` and `count+=1` after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler approach would be if you define a variable *index* and then assign 0th index for the first input then 1st index for the second input, 2nd index for the third input and accordingly increase the index variable everytime you have a new value.

```
a=input('Line: ').upper()
index = 0
ae = []
while a:
    ae.append(a[index])
    index += 1
    a=input('Line: ').upper()
    print(ae)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this with the index generated by `enumerate` instead:

```
from functools import partial
print(''.join(s[i] for i, s in enumerate(iter(partial(input, 'Line: '), ''))).upper())
```

Comment: While technically correct, I think you're writing for a different audience. "a student at a school studying python" who has problems with arrays will not process this. And for production code, it's just not acceptable with the complexity. It's closer to code golf...

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input('Total Lines: '))
ans = ''
col = 0 #column 
while col < n:
 a = input('\nLine: ').upper()
 ans += a[col:col+1] #this what you were looking for

 # a[start:stop] start (inclusive) stop (exclusive)
 col+=1 

print('\n'+ans)
'''
hello
01234 <-- col
'''

'''
input:
4
1rooop
c2rdboard
ch3ssboard
bil4board

1234
'''
```